# Rails: helper method output # instead of correct value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**resource_helper.rb**

```
 def show_checkbox resources
    resources.each do |resource|
      resource.name 
    end.join(' ').html_safe
  end
```

**view**

```
<%= show_checkbox resource %>
```

This code will output # ,I am sure the value inside is correct. But not sure why it output #

Comment: there is not enough information here for us to really help you. can you show us the content of `resource`? More context maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `resources.map`, not `resources.each`.

`each` will return the value you're iterating over, not the content of the block - giving you something like `#<Resource:34531231>`. The rest is interpreted as a HTML tag, leaving you with just the `#` showing.

`map` will return the value of the block, turning an array of Resource objects into an array of string names, as you want.